# Проверка по БД и сделать элемент неактивным.

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

есть тег select с данными записи по времени, как сделать проверку из БД? если время занято, то делать поле неактивным.

mysqli_query + аякс ?

Comment: приложите таблицу из бд, и поясните что значит "если время занято"

Comment: $res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT time from sch1324 WHERE time='$time' and `master` = '$master' and `date_order` = '$date_order' ");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if ($count>0)

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c849224/v849224680/449d8/e_1YDXdFFO0.jpg

Comment: ну во первых добавить в optins атрибуты between, to, так будет проще узнать подом значения для сравнения без регулярок

Comment: вы выбрали в select "от xx:xx и до yy:yy" и хотите чтобы если в таблице существует запись с датой, находящейся в этом промежутке, то какое-то поле будет не активным??? я все верно понял? поле select??

Comment: да, всё верно .

Comment: как у Вас данные в бд хранятся, и число что, не имеет значения, только время?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option between="2018-05-10 03:26:00" to="2018-05-10 04:00:00">03:26 - 04:00</option>
        <option between="2018-05-10 04:26:00" to="2018-05-10 05:00:00">04:26 - 05:00</option>
        <option between="2018-05-10 05:26:00" to="2018-05-10 06:00:00">05:26 - 06:00</option>
        <option between="2018-03-30 01:12:30" to="2018-04-04 03:09:00">01:12 - 03:09</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#mySelect").on('change', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'query.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'between':$("#mySelect option:selected").attr('between'),'to':$("#mySelect option:selected").attr('to')},
            success: function(res){
                if (res == 'true')
                {
                    $("#mySelect").prop("disabled", true);
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('request error');
            },
        });
    });
});
```

query.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["to"]) && isset($_POST["between"]))
{
    $to = $_POST["to"];
    $between = $_POST["between"];

    $host = 'localhost'; // адрес сервера 
    $database = 'portal'; // имя базы данных
    $user = 'root'; // имя пользователя
    $password = ''; // пароль

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

    $query ="SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE date BETWEEN '". $between ."' AND '". $to ."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
    $rows = 0;
    if($result)
    {
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }

    if ($rows == 0) echo 'false'; else echo 'true';
}
?>
```

> Тольк в коде выходит если вы деактивируете `select`, то он уже не активируется. Для активации сами думайте (этого условия в вопросе не было)

Comment: спасибо за помощь.